# Why we have to return a deep copy of the object in the fetch method in array structure?

Tags: java, arrays, deep-copy

```
return data[j].deepCopy();
```

Why do I have to return the deep copy of the object in the fetch method in array structure? Why can't I simply return the data[j]?

I would be very grateful if you also clarify me the concept of deep, shallow and cloning in java. I am beginner level programmer.

```
package objectsortapp;

public class SortedArray {
    private Person[] data; // reference to array data
    private int next; // place where next item will be inserted
    
    public SortedArray(int max) // constructor
    {
        data = new Person[max]; // create the array with max elements
        next = 0; // array is empty
    } // end constructor
    
    public Person fetch(String last) // find a specific person based on last name
    {
        int j=0;
        for(j=0; j<next; j++) // iterate through the loop to find it
        {
            if((data[j].getLast()).equalsIgnoreCase(last)) // compare the entry in the array to the parameter value
                break;
        }
        
        if(j==next)
        {
            return null; // person with that last name was not found
        }
        else
        {
            return data[j].deepCopy(); // person is found, so return a deep copy of their node
        }
    } // end fetch
}
```

Comment: Who said you have to?

Comment: We don't know what a `Person` Object is. We don't know if `deepCopy ( )` has been defined for `Person`. Since the return type is `Person` and `data` is an array of `Person`, `return data[j]` should not generate a *compiler error*. But, we don't have enough information to say that the `deepCopy ()` method should or should not be used.

Comment: Typically, returning a copy is meant to prevent modifications to the original object. Whether or not that's required is entirely up to the design/contract of the code, which is decided by the developer(s) / designer(s). Though if the object is _immutable_, then returning a copy is superfluous.

Comment: Also see [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/6395627).

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Why do I have to return the deep copy of the object in the fetch method in array structure? Why can't I simply return the data[j]? ..."*

It appears to just be what the *fetch* method does.

You can always create an alternate method, to return the actual object.

And, on that note, it would be more useful to encapsulate a *non deep-copying* method.

Here is an example.

```java
public Person fetchDeepCopy(String last) {
    return fetch(last).deepCopy();
}
    
public Person fetch(String last) // find a specific person based on last name
{
    int j=0;
    for(j=0; j<next; j++) // iterate through the loop to find it
    {
        if((data[j].getLast()).equalsIgnoreCase(last)) // compare the entry in the array to the parameter value
            break;
    }

    if(j==next)
    {
        return null; // person with that last name was not found
    }
    else
    {
        return data[j]; // person is found, so return a deep copy of their node
    }
} // end fetch
```

Comment: The question is: "Why are deep copies necessary". This does not answer the stated question at all. If anything it appears to advocate allowing returning a not-deep copy which is a very bad idea, i.e., an answer that makes things worse.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, yeah it's like what _"ham is to a hamster"_.  I almost fell over that was so funny.

Comment: It's a fairly common saying and leads to the proper conclusions (which is: Whenever 'is java like javascript' comes up, assume the answer is no, that tends to lead you to the right conclusions'). And, of course, that was a comment. Comments are the right place for notes and suggestions tangential to the central question. Answers are not.